# How Do I Change the Height of my Navbar?

Tags: css, class, navbar

I use a website builder, and there is a custom CSS box, but how do I make my navbar thin like Twitter's navbar? The navbar class is: container

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking questions for code examples, you should add code and the attempted solutions you have which didn't work. Otherwise there's a large change your question will be closed.

Comment: To Xareyo: .container height:200px

Comment: To Patrick: OK, sorry.

Comment: Hey @Phineas0510, instead of writing it as To Patrick, use `@` it will also notify them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty hard to provide an absolute answer for without any CSS and HTML, but you should be able to set (where 40px is a sample height)

```
.container{
  height:40px;
}
```

If that fails, you likely have a rule with a [higher level of specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), so either alter that directly (dont), or extend the above to match or beat it (do).

If you want to play dirty, use `!important` (**not** recommended)

```
.container{
  height:40px!important;
}
```

Depending on the other CSS rules you have in place, you may need to set other properties to get the desired effect, e.g.(and this is a bad example):

```
.container{
  height:40px;
  max-height:40px;
  min-height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Not at all, you're welcome

Comment: There is only one problem, it cuts off some of my BG.

Comment: Change the height (40px) to a value that works for you

Comment: I did that, but 40px is the value I want, but the BG is still cut off.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put that for the last question.

Comment: If your background is cut off, you can always use padding on the body.

Comment: @Ranveer OK then, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of twitter, lets take the example of stack overflow. Class would be `container`.

```
.container {
  max-height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; 
}
```

You are more likely to use max and min properties to make the navbar stay at the full of the top of page.

Other properties are just for styling nothing else. The height depends on the value you provide in the `height` attribute, you can use `max-` or even `min-` or `height` they would work.

Hey, edit your code:

```
.container {
  height: 200px; // change this value..
}
```

Comment: You're welcome dear brother! :) The thing is, to edit the `height: xxxx` edit it and make it let say `100px` :) You will see the height will shorten :)

Comment: I tried that, and it worked, BUT, it cuts out some of the BG.